# Persisting data to AsyncStorage when not in foreground

Tags: react-native, react-state-management

I'm using Context to have the data updated within the App, however that data has to be saved to disk for nexts executions. So I have to AsyncStorage it when the users closes/minimizes the app. I'm aware of AppState and that can handle app state changes. The question is WHERE to put the handle state change code if I have multiple screens ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your root component(App.js/index.js). In this way, that code will always be executed.